# Create new-line in .replace()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, replace, newline

Everywhere I look, people say do this:

```
 .replace(/\"/g, '<br />')
```

but is just prints < br /> in the string..

I'm using this in a custom pipe in Angular.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let message of messages" [routerLink]="['/members', 
 messageContainer == 'Outbox' ? message.recipientId : 
 message.senderId]" [queryParams]="{tab:'3'}">
   <td>{{message.content | jsonpipe}}<br/></td>
```

'message is an array of JSON objects

```
@Pipe({ name: 'jsonpipe' })
export class Jsonpipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    let newStr = '';
    newStr = value.replace(/{/g, '').replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/}/g, 
    '').replace(/:/g, ': ').replace(/,/g, '\<br>');
    return newStr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your string is being HTML escaped, your might need a way to set raw HTML (which is a dangerous thing to do by the way)

Comment: I've never seen anyone saying that you should replace quotes with `<br>` tags. Where did you look?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? On what string are you calling this, and what is the expected result? What happens with the result string, where is it rendered (that might matter for displaying newlines)?

Comment: I just wrote that as an example, but I was assuming the character being replaced shouldn't matter..

Comment: newStr = value.replace(/{/g, '').replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/}/g, '').replace(/:/g, ': ').replace(/,/g, '\<br>'); ....... '. This is my actual code and it all works except the line break. It is being applied to a JSON string in the HTML